# Proof by contradiction1

Tags: combinatorics

Use proof by contradiction to show that every integer greater than 11 is a sum of two composite numbers

My Solution:

Statement: For all integers $x$, if $x>11$, then $x = y + z$ whereby $y$ and $z$ are any composite numbers.

Proof by contradiction: There exists an integer $x$ such that $x>11$ and $x$ is not equals to $y + z$ whereby $y$ and $z$ are some composite numbers.

However, now, I am stuck, and I don't know how to carry on?

(Hint provided by the answer sheet: Are $n-4$, $n-6$ and $n-8$ all prime?)
Honestly, I don't even know how to use this hint to solve this question. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for hint: One of the numbers $x-4$, $x-6$ and $x-8$ is divisible by $3$ and all of them are greater than $3$.

> Therefore $x = (x-4)+4$, $x = (x-6)+6$, or $x = (x-8)+8$.

Comment: Sorry njguliyev, I still don't get how to carry on?

Comment: Say $x-8$ is not prime. Then you can take $y=x-8$ and $z=8$.

Comment: Ok, but if x=12, then (x-4) = 8, and then it means that y = 8, a composite number. Also z=4, a composite number. However, x is by right not equals to y+z. So there is a contradiction?

Comment: I don't really get this part?

Comment: No, $x=y+z$. Contradiction is used only in hint, i.e. to prove that at least one of the numbers $x−4$, $x−6$ and $x−8$ is not prime.

Comment: Ok.. sorry I still don't get how to do this question

Answer (score 0):

See, You want to prove that $n>11$ is a sum of two composite numbers.

Given hint is to check "Are $n−4$, $n−6$ and $n−8$ all prime?"

Suppose one of then is composite then :

$n=(n-4)+4$ (if $n-4$ is not prime) (Thus $n$ is sum of two composite numbers $n-4$ and $4$)

$n=(n-6)+6$ (if $n-6$ is not prime)(Thus $n$ is sum of two composite numbers $n-6$ and $6$)

$n=(n-8)+8$ (if $n-8$ is not prime)(Thus $n$ is sum of two composite numbers $n-8$ and $8$)

So, all you have to now do is to "prove that not all of $n-4$, $n-6$ and $n-8$ are prime"

Can you do that??

P.S : You do not really need a "proof by contradiction" to see this.. Do you want to prove by contradiction or it is specified "to prove by contradiction"??

Comment: This question specified to prove by contradiction only

Comment: Really?? If it is so, then i am not very sure about the way to go... Do you at least understand by my solution that it is actually true???  By given hint, I strongly feel that this would be the "type of solution" that you are looking for..